# Jupyter QtConsole syntaxerror with matplotlib inline

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter

Ok I have been at this problem for some time now, and I am at a loss.

I am running Jupyter QtConsole and trying to run a python script.

```
from __future__ import division
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline
```

The QtConsole keeps giving me an error:

```
run test.py
  File "/home/Bob/Desktop/test.py", line 5
    %matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

From what I read this is Ipython specific code and it should work in the Jupyter QtConsole which I load by going to terminal and typing:

```
bob@bob-laptop:~/Desktop$ jupyter qtconsole
```

It gives this in the terminal but then loads the qtconsole.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/paths.py:62: UserWarning: IPython dir '/home/bob/.ipython' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  " using a temp directory.".format(ipdir))
Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/paths.py:62: UserWarning: IPython dir '/home/bob/.ipython' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  " using a temp directory.".format(ipdir))
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start qtconsole, type %matplotlib inline on the console and there after all the plots will appear inline.

Hope this helps.